# Using PlaceID for Google Maps details returning NOT_FOUND

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am able get the google places details (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/) when using the reference param (but google mentions its deprecated in favor of the placeid).  The placeid works most of the time, but i am receiving a not_found for several addresses but when i use the location's reference it returns the details results.  What might be the cause of this?

If you search this address:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?key=API_KEY&types=address&language=en_US&input=1770%201st%20highland%20park,%20il&components=country:US

Yields these values:

**placeId** = ChIJS_x5PqPBD4gR5m0bMzpdVcQ

**reference** = ClRJAAAALe7t0O_-a2GP1AbuAFfAydAbxZO4ImyIxFm_btA6YhwEtcSLENlDsdJnx7TG1qZ4RbIP0DTWq5Ye5iIaEwnY_sFE02NwcnVFZasRr_5yID8SEJ94zzKeL_QKZsRt1OgUpNoaFLgO6RqiGV3AX4wDexTwPvxWILWT

---

Using place_id returns "Not Found" with the place/details call, but using the reference returns the details.   What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of 12/22/2016:
There is an ongoing issue with the Google Maps API. You can track it [here](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=11107)